# How does this Go function type "HandlerFunc" work, from the standard library "net/http"

Tags: function, types, go

I'm confused about [this bit of code from the HTTP package](http://golang.org/src/pkg/http/server.go?s=26766:26837#L675):

```
type HandlerFunc func(ResponseWriter, *Request)
func (f HandlerFunc) ServeHTTP(w ResponseWriter, r *Request) {
    f(w, r)
}
```

Why does the `ServeHTTP` method have the exact same signature as it's type - what's the point?

Testing, I discovered that if I pass a random function (`foo`) to the `HandlerFunc`:

```
var bar = HandlerFunc(foo)
```

`bar` becomes an instance of `HandlerFunc` with `foo` as its `ServeHTTP` method. Now I'm really confused about how on earth this works.

If I have more than one methods on a type, how do I know which one is going to be attached to the new instance and with what name or order?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This approach allows you to use a function in a context that's expecting a `Handler`.

What happens is, there's a `Handler` interface:

```
    type Handler interface {
        ServeHTTP(ResponseWriter, *Request)
    }
```

and various functions are declared to accept parameters that are declared to belong to this interface — for example:

```
    func TimeoutHandler(h Handler, ns int64, msg string) Handler {
        f := func() <-chan int64 {
            return time.After(ns)
        }
        return &timeoutHandler{h, f, msg}
    }
```

What this means is that when you invoke such a function, you have to pass in an object belonging to a type that *satisfies* this interface, which is to say, a type that has a `ServeHTTP` method with the appropriate signature. (In Go, unlike some languages, a type doesn't need to explicitly implement an interface, it just needs to have the methods specified by the interface.)

So, the code-snippet that you quote:

```
type HandlerFunc func(ResponseWriter, *Request)
func (f HandlerFunc) ServeHTTP(w ResponseWriter, r *Request) {
    f(w, r)
}
```

creates a type `HandlerFunc` that's based on `func(ResponseWriter, *Request)`, but augments the type with a method called `ServeHTTP` with an appropriate signature, so that it satisfies the `Handler` interface. This `ServeHTTP` method just calls the function itself. So, if `f` is a function with the right signature, you could write something like this:

```
var h HandlerFunc = f    // h == f, but converted to a HandlerFunc
                         // so it satisfies the Handler interface.
TimeoutHandler(h, 1000000, "timed out")
```

To clarify a few things about this:

> Testing, I discovered that if I pass a random function (`foo`) to the `HandlerFunc`:
>
> ```
> var bar = HandlerFunc(foo)
> ```
>
> `bar` becomes an instance of `HandlerFunc` with `foo` as its `ServeHTTP` method. Now I'm really confused about how on earth this works.

Firstly, it's more correct to say that you've *converted* a random function `foo` *to type `HandlerFunc`*, rather than that you've *passed* the function *to* `HandlerFunc` as though `HandlerFunc` were a function. (The `HandlerFunc(foo)` notation is a typecast; you could just as well write `var bar HandlerFunc = foo` and let the conversion happen implicitly.)

Secondly, it's more correct to say that `bar` has a `ServeHTTP` method that *invokes* `foo`, than that `foo` itself actually *is* the `ServeHTTP` method.

Does that make sense?

Comment: +1 for the explanation.  It's pretty cool that functions can be treated the same way as objects can when it comes to satisfying interfaces.

Comment: Thank you, this makes things a lot clearer. Go is really an unusual language but inside, everything is very simple. Happy new year btw :).